# Serial multiple mediated model in lavaan not calculating standard errors, Z-values, and P values for defined parameters

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, lavaan, controlling-for-a-variable

I am trying to run the following model in Lavaan, in which AM, RM, and CU are latent variables. It also has three control variables (CV1, CV2, and CV3).

[image: Model tested]

I have written the code that is included at the end of the post.  I have two doubts:
Should I also include the CV when calculating the total effect, and indirect effects? If so, how should I do it?

When I get the output, everything seems to work fine (fit indices are good), but for the total effect and the indirect effects, for which I cannot get the standard error or the P value. It is shown like this:

[image: Error shown]

This is the code I am using:

```
# First set of mediators
AF ~ a1*X + c1*CV1 + c2*CV2 + c3*CV3
AK ~ a2*X + c4*CV1 + c5*CV2 + c6*CV3
AC ~ a3*X + c7*CV1 + c8*CV2 + c9*CV3

# Second set of mediators
AM ~ b1*AF + b4*AK + b7*AC + c10*CV1+c11*CV2+c12*CV3
RM ~ b2*AF + b5*AK + b8*AC + c13*CV1+c14*CV2+c15*CV3
CU ~ b3*AF + b6*AK + b9*AC + c16*CV1+c17*CV2+c18*CV3

# Third mediator
CM ~ d1*AM + d2*RM + d3*CU + c19*CV1 + c20*CV2 + c21*CV3
# Fourth mediator
RP ~ e1*AM + e2*RM + e3*CU + f1*CM + c22*CV1 + c23*CV2 + c24*CV3
# Direct effect
Y ~ g1*RP + z1*X + h1*AM + h2*RM + h3*CU + c25*CV1 + c26*CV2 + c27*CV3
# Indirect effects
ind_eff1:=a1*b1*d1*f1*g1
ind_eff2:=a1*b2*d2*f1*g1
ind_eff3:=a1*b3*d3*f1*g1
ind_eff4:=a2*b4*d1*f1*g1
ind_eff5:=a2*b5*d2*f1*g1
ind_eff6:=a2*b6*d3*f1*g1
ind_eff7:=a3*b7*d1*f1*g1
ind_eff8:=a3*b8*d2*f1*g1
ind_eff9:=a3*b9*d3*f1*g1
ind_eff10:=a1*b1*e1*g1
ind_eff11:=a1*b2*e2*g1
ind_eff12:=a1*b3*e3*g1
ind_eff13:=a2*b4*e1*g1
ind_eff14:=a2*b5*e2*g1
ind_eff15:=a2*b6*e3*g1
ind_eff16:=a3*b7*e1*g1
ind_eff17:=a3*b8*e2*g1
ind_eff18:=a3*b9*e3*g1
ind_eff19:=a1*b1*h1
ind_eff20:=a1*b2*h2
ind_eff21:=a1*b3*h3
ind_eff22:=a2*b4*h1
ind_eff23:=a2*b5*h2
ind_eff24:=a2*b6*h3
ind_eff25:=a3*b7*h1
ind_eff36:=a3*b8*h2
ind_eff27:=a3*b9*h3
#Total effect
total:= z1 + (a1*b1*d1*f1*g1) + (a1*b2*d2*f1*g1) + (a1*b3*d3*f1*g1) + 
    (a2*b4*d1*f1*g1)  + (a2*b5*d2*f1*g1) + (a2*b6*d3*f1*g1) + 
    (a3*b7*d1*f1*g1) + (a3*b8*d2*f1*g1) + (a3*b9*d3*f1*g1) + 
    (a1*b1*e1*g1) + (a1*b2*e2*g1) + (a1*b3*e3*g1) + (a2*b4*e1*g1) + 
    (a2*b5*e2*g1) + (a2*b6*e3*g1) + (a3*b7*e1*g1) + (a3*b8*e2*g1) +  
    (a3*b9*e3*g1) + (a1*b1*h1) + (a1*b2*h2) + (a1*b3*h3) + 
    (a2*b4*h1) + (a2*b5*h2) + (a2*b6*h3) + (a3*b7*h1) + (a3*b8*h2) + 
    (a3*b9*h3)

# Estimate parameters
fit_medmed <- sem(medmed, data=smart, std.lv=TRUE, meanstructure=TRUE, 
                  estimator = "ML", se="bootstrap")

# Request Output from SEM
summary(fit_medmed, fit.measures=TRUE, standardized=TRUE)
```

Comment: What are a1*b1*d1*f1*g1 equal to? If their product is zero, is one of them equal to zero?

Comment: do you get warnings after the analysis is done running?